# Thread 1: EXC_Bad_Access (Code=1, address=0x7fff55056148) While Trying to Use Ofstream and an integer data type named count

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access, ofstream

I am currently working to solve Project Euler's Problem #60: http://projecteuler.net/problem=60 (Just in case if you want to try and follow my logic).

The issue is that after I build my code (Which it completes without errors) and then run it, I get the error code "Thread 1: EXC_Bad_Access (Code=1, address=0x7fff55056148)" from the IDE I was using while running it (The IDE's built in debugger I think). More Specifically the error occurs only within my "Combinations" Function. The lines that get highlighted are disabled with "//" comment lines within my combinations function. Thus, currently, my code will run without any errors because all the error-causing lines are disabled as comments. if you de-comment any of those lines or any combination of those lines thereof, the code runs into the same error code listed above.

Personal Comments from Experimentation:
What I found was that any line that has something to do with either ofstream or the integer that I initialized called count causes the error. ofstream kind of makes sense, but even after disabling all lines of code related to ofstream, suddenly the integer count starts creating the error.

Any help would be much appreciated! I am still a beginner with C++, (started about two to three weeks ago.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

/* double x = 2 , y = 2 , b = 3, s = 2; */
/* int z, c = 1, v = 3000; */

int AllPrimes[3000];
/* int AllCombos[2018257871250650][5]; */ // disabled this line for now.

//Used to be within Combinations; Moved here to circumvent "Bad Access" Error

int FindPrimes();
int TestforPrime(double y);
int Combinations();
int WriteArrayToFile(int *ArrayPointer,int ArrayLength, string FileName, char Append);

int main()
{
    cout<<FindPrimes();
    cout<<Combinations();
}

int Combinations() {
    int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, /* ai */ bi, ci, di, ei;
    int ZeroPointBreaker=0;
//ofstream BufferFlushed ("/Users/Yash/Xcode/Projects/Project Euler Programs/Project Euler Problem 60 (Weird Prime Cocatenate Property Problem)/I:O Files/");
int count=0;
int Buffer[9000000][5];
for (i1=0; i1<2996; i1++) {
    count++;
    // cout<<"Index 1 Iteration: "<<i1<<" || Count Value: "<<count<<"\n";
    bi = i1 + 1;
    for (i2=bi; i2<2997; i2++) {
       count++;
      //  cout<<"Index 2 Iteration: "<<i2<<" || Count Value: "<<count<<"\n";
        ci = i2+ 1;
        for (i3=ci; i3<2998; i3++) {
            count++;
            di = i3 + 1;
            for (i4=di; i4<2999; i4++) {
                count++;
                ei = i4 + 1;
                for (i5=ei; i5<3000; i5++) {
                    count++;
                   // Buffer[count][0]=AllPrimes[i1];
                  //  Buffer[count][1]=AllPrimes[i2];
                  //  Buffer[count][2]=AllPrimes[i3];
                 //   Buffer[count][3]=AllPrimes[i4];
                 //   Buffer[count][4]=AllPrimes[i5];
                }
            }
        }
    //Flush Here
    //   count=0;
        /* for (int i=0; i<9000000; i++) {
            if (Buffer[i][1]==0) {ZeroPointBreaker=i; break;}
        } */
  //      for (int i=0; i<ZeroPointBreaker; i++) {
           // BufferFlushed<<Buffer[i][1]<<','<<Buffer[i][2]<<','<<Buffer[i][3]<<','<<Buffer[i][4]<<','<<Buffer[i][5]<<'\n';
       // }
    }
}
//End of Code Statements
    //BufferFlushed.close();
    return 0;
}

int FindPrimes() {
cout.precision(0);
AllPrimes[0]=2;
double b = 3, s = 2;
int z, c = 1, v = 3000;
        while ( c != v ) {
            z = TestforPrime(b);
            if ( z == 1 ) {
                AllPrimes[c]=b;
                c = c + 1;
                s = s + b;
                if ( c == v ) {
                    cout<<fixed<<" Prime="<<b<<" Count="<<c<<" "<<"Sum="<<s<<"\n";
                    int success = WriteArrayToFile(AllPrimes,3000,"/Users/Yash/Xcode/Projects/Project Euler Programs/Project Euler Problem 60 (Weird Prime Cocatenate Property Problem)/I:O Files/AllPrimes.txt",'n');
                    cout<<"\n Write Success (0=Successful): "<<success<<"\n";
                    if (success == 0) {return 0;}
                    else {return 1;}
                }
                else {

                };
            }
            else {

            };
            b = b + 2;
        }
}

int WriteArrayToFile(int *ArrayPointer,int ArrayLength, string FileName, char Append) {
if (Append == 'y') {
    ofstream OutputFile (FileName, ios::app);
        for ( unsigned long long i1=0 ; i1 < ArrayLength ; i1++) {
            OutputFile<<ArrayPointer[i1]<<"\n";
        }
        OutputFile.close();
        return 0;}
else if (Append == 'n') {
    ofstream OutputFile (FileName);
    for ( unsigned long long i1=0 ; i1 < ArrayLength ; i1++) {
        OutputFile<<ArrayPointer[i1]<<"\n";
        }
        OutputFile.close();
        return 0;}
}

int TestforPrime (double y) {
double x = 2;
while ( x <= y ) {
    if ( (( y / x ) - int( y / x )) == 0 ) {
        if ( y == x ) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    x = x + 1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This variable:

```
int Buffer[9000000][5];
```

takes up 45000000 * 4 Bytes. That's 180MB. You can't fit that on the stack. Use a global variable or dynamic allocation (or, more likely, another solution - I haven't looked at the problem itself, so don't know if your solution is "right").